# Example for a nearly injective sequence with subexponential growth

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits

I am searching for a sequence $s_n$ of integers which is nearly injective (there exists an $c \in \mathbb{N}$ so that every value appears at most $c$ times) and there exists an $f : \mathbb{N} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}_+$ with $\frac{f(n)}{log_2n} \rightarrow 0$ so that $|s_n| \leq 2^{2^{f(n)}}$ for every $n \in \mathbb{N}$.

Background: I read a proof about the fact, that there exist endless proofs of the infinitude of prime numbers by Christian Elsholtz. He proves that every sequence of this special form gives us another proof of the infinitude of prime numbers.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please read this text about [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question).

Comment: Thanks @JoséCarlosSantos, I hope it's correct now.

Comment: $s_n=n$ is truly injective, not just nearly, and it satisfies this with $f(n)=1$

Comment: but for $n=5$ we have $s_n = 5 \geq 2^{2^{f(n)}} = 2^{2^1} = 2^2=4$ so this does not satisfie the second condition... @Adam

Comment: @sevenhappyoranges Oh right my mistake. Try $f(n) = \log_2 \log_2 n$ instead

Comment: Thank you, this is a good one! Easy to understand and its working! @Adam